# Groupby to create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

From a dataframe, I want to create a dataframe with new columns if the index is already found without knowing how many columns I will create :

```
pd.DataFrame([["John","guitar"],["Michael","football"],["Andrew","running"],["John","dancing"],["Andrew","cars"]])
```

and I want :

```
pd.DataFrame([["John","guitar","dancing"],["Michael","Football",None],["Andrew","running","cars"]])
```

without knowing how many columns I should create at the start.

Comment: @FFL75 updated with a faster alternative, more suited for large dataframes

Comment: Actually, in my real use case knowing that the value repeat is very great and it is true that in this example it is not stated to show unique values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for get `counter` and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["John","guitar"],
                    ["Michael","football"],
                    ["Andrew","running"],
                    ["John","dancing"],
                    ["Andrew","cars"]], columns=['a','b'])

         a         b
0     John    guitar
1  Michael  football
2   Andrew   running
3     John   dancing
4   Andrew      cars


df = (df1.set_index(['a', df1.groupby('a').cumcount()])['b']
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(-1)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x+1))
print (df)

         0         1        2
0   Andrew   running     cars
1     John    guitar  dancing
2  Michael  football      NaN
```

Or aggregate `list` and create new dictionary by constructor:

```
s = df1.groupby('a')['b'].agg(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).reset_index()
print (df)
         a         0        1
0   Andrew   running     cars
1     John    guitar  dancing
2  Michael  football     None
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["John","guitar"],["Michael","football"],["Andrew","running"],["John","dancing"],["Andrew","cars"]], columns = ['person','hobby'])
```

You can groupby `person` and search for [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) in `hobby`. Then use `.apply(pd.Series)` to expand lists into columns:

```
df.groupby('person').hobby.unique().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
    person         0        1
0   Andrew   running     cars
1     John    guitar  dancing
2  Michael  football      NaN
```

In the case of having a large dataframe, try the more efficient alternative:

```
df = df.groupby('person').hobby.unique()
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist(), index=df.index).reset_index()
```

Which in essence does the same, but avoids looping over rows when applying `pd.Series`.

Comment: What is problem with your answer - why unique? why `pd.Series` what is really slow?

Comment: Yes agree that `.apply(pd.Series)` isn't the best choice for very larges dataframes, but it will do the job if that is not the case. "why unique" - well I assume that what OP wants is to have record of which hobbies are present in the dataframe for each person. Otherwise please let me know @ffl75

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column names being `['person', 'activity']` you can do

```
df_out = df.groupby('person').agg(list).reset_index()
df_out = pd.concat([df_out, pd.DataFrame(df_out['activity'].values.tolist())], axis=1)
df_out = df_out.drop('activity', 1)
```

giving you

```
    person         0        1
0   Andrew   running     cars
1     John    guitar  dancing
2  Michael  football     None
```